# How to rearrange elements within list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 4)], 
 [('c', 2), ('b', 4), ('a', 2)], 
 [('b', 6), ('c', 7), ('a', 5)]]
```

I want to rearrange the tuples and create a new list of lists with each list having members with similar property like `[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 5)]`  or `[('b', 2), ('c', 2)]`.

How could I achieve this the tuples and lists are of arbitrary length?

I have tried iterating through each list but the length of the tuples is making it hard.

Comment: All of these tuples have exactly two elements.  Do you really need to handle arbitrary length tuples?

Comment: Also, how do you define "similar property"?  Does that mean the first element is the same, or the second element is the same?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So what takes priority? In your example new list you seem to group the `'a'`s first then the `2`s. However, `('a', 2)` is only in the first group and not in the second.

Comment: @JohnGordon They are fixed at runtime. It could be the first,second,third, or last element.

Comment: If a particular tuple shares its first element with another tuple, and its second element with a different tuple, how do you decide which grouping to use?  It's very hard to answer questions when you don't give all the details of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes straightforward if we:

- Flatten the list.
- Sort it by the first element in each tuple. (The subsequent step relies on having done this first.)
- Group the tuples by the first element.
- Map that grouping out to just get the values as lists.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [[('a',1),('b',2),('c',4)],[('c',2),('b',4),('a',2)],[('b',6),('c',7),('a',5)]]
>>> lst2 = [y for x in lst for y in x]
>>> lst2
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 4), ('c', 2), ('b', 4), ('a', 2), ('b', 6), ('c', 7), ('a', 5)]
>>> [
...   list(v) 
...   for k, v in groupby(
...     sorted(lst2, key=itemgetter(0)), 
...     key=itemgetter(0)
...   )
... ]
[[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 5)], [('b', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 6)], [('c', 4), ('c', 2), ('c', 7)]]
```

You could then subsequently sort by the second element in the tuple.

```
>>> lst3 = [
...   list(v) 
...   for k, v in groupby(
...     sorted(lst2, key=itemgetter(0)), 
...     key=itemgetter(0)
...   )
... ]
>>> [sorted(x, key=itemgetter(1)) for x in lst3]
[[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 5)], [('b', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 6)], [('c', 2), ('c', 4), ('c', 7)]]
```

Or since we know the first elements are all the same:

```
>>> [sorted(x) for x in lst3]
[[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 5)], [('b', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 6)], [('c', 2), ('c', 4), ('c', 7)]]
```

Comment: You can also use `lst2 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)` to flatten the list lazily; `sorted` can realize the list while sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict` to group the tuples

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Original list of lists
original_list = [[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 4)], 
                 [('c', 2), ('b', 4), ('a', 2)], 
                 [('b', 6), ('c', 7), ('a', 5)]]

# defaultdict to store grouped tuples
grouped_tuples = defaultdict(list)

# Group tuples by their keys
for inner_list in original_list:
    for tuple_item in inner_list:
        key, value = tuple_item
        grouped_tuples[key].append(value)

# Create a new list of lists with grouped tuples
new_list = [[(key, value) for value in grouped_tuples[key]] for key in grouped_tuples]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 5)], [('b', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 6)], [('c', 4), ('c', 2), ('c', 7)]]
```